# SQL Server distributed login with windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, impersonation

I am new to SQL Server, I am planning to build a distributed application in Java for SQL Server. I am curious to know that if there is a way to handle the following scenarios:

1. UserA logs in on MachineA and chooses **Windows authentication** as credentials in app. My application's 2nd component is on MachineB (components communicate using RESTful web services) and MachineB has SQL Server installed on it. MachineB has the code to connect to SQL Server.

   I want to know what are the steps to make this happen, is it possible to use windows authentication here?
2. UserA logs in on MachineA and uses **Windows authentication**, code to connect is on MachineB and SQL Server is on MachineC. What are the required steps here to make this happen, connection string and if I need to make any domain etc.

Comment: User credentials are not included in the connection string when Windows authentication is specified.  Instead, the security token of the thread establishing the connection is used.  Is your requirement to connect to SQL Server using the end user's security credentials regardless of the number of hops?  Are all of the tiers running Windows?

Comment: All machines use Windows. Components communicate by webservices(stateless). Want to use whatever credentials userA provides on MachineA, regardless of # of hops.

Comment: As already posted this _should_ work but in my experience usually does't unless you have a very knowledgeable infrastructure person to help. If you have an external unhelpful unimaginative process bound external support provider managing your servers forget it.

Comment: Also keep in mind with this set up that you should ensure you only allow incoming connections to the SQL Server from MachineB (not directly from MachineA). Otherwise your users can connect directly to the SQL Server via windows authentication.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlupdates/archive/2014/12/05/sql-server-kerberos-and-spn-quick-reference.aspx includes more detained steps on configuring Kerberos delegation.  Getting this to work with many moving parts can be a bit real pain and, as Nick mentioned, requires a good infrastructure team.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all machines are on the same DOMAIN, yes it will work. You may need to configure Kerberos (SetSPN) to make sure the service is trusted. You should check [Microsoft® Kerberos Configuration Manager for SQL Server®](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046) from Microsoft. If Java is used from a Web site, you will also need to configure a SPN for this service as well. When it's all configured, To connect using Java, your ConnectionString should look like this:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;
```

Hope it help.